# Canon Powershot SD1400 IS stuck in 640x480 mode?

Tags: canon, resolution, sdcard, powershot

For some reason, every photograph I take on my PowerShot is saved at 640x480 despite the claims that the camera has a 14.1 megapixel resolution.

I only have a 1gb SD card inside the camera, and am wondering if this is some kind of "hidden feature" to save space and allow more photographs to be taken on such a small card? I have looked online, in the manual, and on the camera, and cannot find any way to change the resolution that the camera saves photographs at, as I have seen on other digital cameras.

Does anybody have any advice?

Comment: I have just discovered that if you press the center button "func/set" while in photo taking mode, it pulls up a menu that will let you choose the shooting resolution. Baffling why that piece of information wasn't in the instruction manual...

Comment: It's there on page 72 "Changing the Recording Pixel Setting
(Image Size)" in PSSD1400IS_IXUS130IS_CUG_EN.pdf

Comment: @user24601, it's baffling why it isn't an option in the main menus too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things that affect picture resolution on most Canon Powershot cameras:

- You explicitly changed the resolution. You can change it back by using the Func menu by pressing the center of the 4-way controller. Then navigate until we see something called either Resolution or Size and you can select the resolution you truly want.
- Scene modes. Certain modes require more processing power or do something called pixel-binning which produces a lower resolution image. This is often the case for low-light and effect modes. Going back to a normal mode, even full Auto, will restore your previous resolution selection.
- Date Imprint (or Postcard) setting. This will often reduce the resolution to 2 megapixels. Turning the feature off will let you select larger resolutions.